# How to install iOS 13 on iPhone 6s?

Tags: iphone, software-update, ios

What I’ve tried so far:

[image]

On this screen I hit ‘Download and Install’ and then ‘Continue’:

[image]

After that, nothing ever happens. I’ve waited for ~10h, left it connected to the charger the whole night.

My device: iPhone 6s 16Gb still with iOS 12.4.

Is it not possible to go directly from 12.4 to 13.1.3? What to do now?

Comment: The problem might be with the temporary app removal rather than the upgrade itself. Can you remove some apps yourself (to reinstall later) to get enough free storage?

Comment: Try removing the update from the iPhone and updating via iTunes.

Comment: Indeed, the temporary App removal didn't work. When I removed a big App the update did install. Seriously Apple?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a risky proposition, but it’s what I would do if I was in your position. Obviously I cannot test it myself. Use at your own risk, etc.

1. ***This is a highly important step!!!***  Make a backup of your iPhone, either to iTunes or to iCloud. (Ideally, both.) If iTunes, be sure to set an encryption password.
2. Reset the device: Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.
3. When it restarts, don’t bother configuring anything, just skip through the setup steps as quickly as possible.
4. Run the update.
5. When the update is complete, run Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings again.
6. Restore iPhone from backup.

That should give you your current setup but with the new version of iOS.

Unfortunately, some things do not carry over after a restore, so you will have to reconfigure some apps, but I think it’s the best chance that you have.

## If you want to try a less-drastic option…

I would recommend going to Settings > General > iPhone Storage and looking at which apps are taking up the most space. Deleting them manually might help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it!  iOS 13 breaks the iPhone 6s in important ways.

- Mail doesn't work properly. Some messages don't download at all, mail
  retrieval is very slow, and sometimes only the message header is
  downloaded.
- Battery life is reduced by about 25 percent (my
  guesstimate, I have to hook up a charger at least three times a day).
- The new sharing UI is defective.  Often when I try to share via
  e-mail I get a message box.  The fields are completely blank.  And I
  can't type in it.

Best,
Tony